# Bindable objects in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

What makes an object to be Bindable in .net ?

Ive been answered once that it is the Ienumerable class which makes it Bindable.

However when I look at DataTAble ( System.Data) , it doesn't implemenets Ienumerable :

```
public class DataTable : MarshalByValueComponent, 
                         IListSource, 
                         ISupportInitializeNotification,
                         ISupportInitialize, 
                         ISerializable, 
                         IXmlSerializable
{...}
```

and still , we can write :

```
myObj.DataSource=myDataTable;
myObj.Bind();
```

help ?

Comment: for WPF (but I believe it is the same for Winfroms) The Binding system just looks at Public properties on any .Net object and uses that for Binding. There is no special interface to implement (unless you want to notify for changes you implement INotifyPropertChanged.

Comment: It's `Rows` property (`DataRowCollection` class) inherits from `InternalDataCollectionBase` which implements `ICollection, IEnumerable`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter but I bind to the Datatable object... **not  to its** Rows property .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataTable` implements `IListSource` by providing the `DataTable.DefaultView`

`DataView` implements `IBindingList` which is what the binding targets actually use

Comment: but im not calling *DefaultView*

Comment: Right -- that's the whole point of the IListSource interface. It allows the implementer to specify a *different* list source than itself. So when you give a data binding component a DataTable the component uses IListSource to ask for the actual list. DataTable then returns DataTable.DefaultView

Comment: So it isnt related to ienumerable ?

Comment: IListSource allows a non-IList object to specify a different IList. It basically acts as a proxy to the "real" list. DataTable implements this by using its DefaultView

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN

The DataGridView class supports the standard Windows Forms data-binding model. This means the data source can be of any type that implements one of the following interfaces:

The IList interface, including one-dimensional arrays.

The IListSource interface, such as the DataTable and DataSet classes.

The IBindingList interface, such as the BindingList class.

The IBindingListView interface, such as the BindingSource class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx

Comment: Ilist implements ienumerable  , also  IBindingList ... im looking for the basic condition.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, from what I understand any object is bindable for WPF binding.
but changes of values are not being notified by default, it must implement INPC,INCC..
For winforms the situation is very diffrent.
So it really depends on what type of binding you asking about specifically.